# How to automatically start ASP.NET MVC web app before executing Selenium Web-driver tests?

Tags: c#, selenium, iis, teamcity, mstest

I would like to test ASP.NET MVC webpage by MSTest using selenium driver. I suppose I need to start the ISS and start web application somehow, get the url of the web app (localhost at some port) and then start test.

There are many examples how to use selenium driver but they all work with already configured urls.

My expectation is following:

1. Anyone who just clone the git repository with this web app and open solution in Visual studio, click run all test. The web app is started and test are executed.
2. It should also work as part of continual integration (for example with Teamcity) where these unittest are executed using MSTest on different computers.
3. It would be nice if this solution works also on computers without Visual Studio Installed (just nuget, MSBuild, MSTest and various SDKs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you should be able to do here.

1) If you have Visual Studio, you can write a powershell script that will spin up the local site you need to run the tests against. [This may help you.](https://ericflemingblog.wordpress.com/2015/09/15/starting-iis-express-using-the-visual-studio-applicationconfig-file/)
You'll then need to also create a script that will run your selenium scripts after the site starts. I've only done this with Microsoft WebTests, but I've seen the similarities with Selenium. I'd look into running your selenium scripts from a powershell script, then combine these two, and have a batch file which new users can just click and to run the tests.

2) You can certainly run these scripts from TeamCity, there just may be some additional configuration like installing necessary tools on the build server. TeamCity has build in tools to run these tests though, so look to utilize that.